# Probability of winning $m$ games in $N$ competitions

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A slight variation on probability of winning a number of games

A competition involves winning a number of games consecutively. The probability of a player winning any game is $p$.
A typical competition might involve $6$ rounds (but it could be more or less - typically in the range $4 - 7$) and so, in a $6$ round event, a player must win $6$ games consecutively to win the competition (and cant win more than this nor does he have to lose a game to end his 'run')

A player takes part in $N$ independent competitions over a period of time.
What are the chances of him winning a total of $m$ games in these $N$ competitions?

I reckon the probability of any particular combination of Wins and losses is
$p^m(1-p)^N$ - ignoring the fact that they do not have to lose a game if they win the whole competition
But I am having real trouble working out the number of such combinations for different $m$ and $N$.
Help greatly appreciated

Eventually I am interested in questions such as
What are the chances a player will win more than $x$ games; or at least $x$ games; or less than $x$ games.

Comment: There are $N$ independent experiments (competitions) and each of them has the same probability to succeed (the player wins).... Doesn't this smell like binomial distribution with parameter $N$? Can you find the probability on success? To be found is an expression for $P(S=m)$ where $S$ denotes the number of successes. Maybe I misinterpreted things. I am suspicuous because it sounds a bit too easy.

Comment: If each competition is a knock-out (stop playing if you lose a game) then generating functions (or recursion) would give you a method of calculation though probably not a closed form

Comment: drhab - As Henry says: Although the competitions are independent, the games within a competition are not. In B&W balll terms if your first ball is black (lose) you cant pick any more. If your first ball is white (win) you get to pick again

Comment: So I think . . . .  the probability of any specific combination of wins ending in a loss is (p^M)*((1-p)^N) . . . .  The number of combinations available for a specific N and M is ((N+M-1)!)/((N-1!)*(M!)) where ! is the  Factorial function. . . .   And the probability of a particular result (a given N & M) is simply the product of these two quantities . . . . But I'm not sure this is right and  cant think of any way to verify this. Comments and Suggestions welcome . . . . As are suggestions on how to add line breaks!!!